# Emacs: "M-%" shortcut being treated as simply "%", even when "M-" works fine

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, ubuntu-18.04

I have no clue as to why my Emacs won't take "M-%" as the shortcut for replace. Even more strangely, in the message window it states "% is undefined", as if it doesn't get that I'm also pressing the Meta key. But the Meta key works fine: if I press "M-x" I get the expected result. As an additional information, I can see in the menu that "M-%" is bound to replace, as expected.

This is Emacs'a about:
GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21)
 of 2017-09-22, modified by Debian

Comment: Does it work if you run emacs as `$ emacs -Q`? If it does, then it's probably an issue with your init file and we'd need more information about that.

Comment: Good guess, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Sounds like your Window manager or some other program might be interfering. Can you use `ESC %`?

Comment: `ESC %` works, indeed

Comment: You can also use `C-h c` to see what Emacs sees (though I guess it would be `%` in your case and that's not very informative), and also `xev` to see what the window manager sees (look for `state` and `keycode`). You can also try other Alt-Shift-foo key combinations to see whether they have the same problem. Also, try Emacs in a GUI versus in a terminal. Good luck!

Comment: `C-h c` reads `M-5 runs the command digit-argument`, and `xev` outputs `state 0x2008, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L)`.

Comment: Oh, and in terminal has the same behavior.

Comment: try `C-h k M-S-%`, maybe shift meta is bound in your ubuntu settings

Comment: I realized that it toggles the message (be it `C-h c` or `C-h k`): it interprets the keys as `M-5 digit-argument` or as `% self-insert-command`. I guess it's toggling how to interpret the keys in my laptop keyboard. I will try a different keyboard and report back.

Comment: Are you using a bi-lingual (or multi-lingual) setup?
Did you at some point set alt-shift as switching input sources?

Comment: I think you're right, @AmnonHarel! This was on my old computer using Lubuntu, I do use two inputs, and if I remember correctly alt-shift was the input switch there. Will test later. Thanks!